# Whether it is a lattice? Why or Why not?

Tags: lattice-orders

[image]Whether it is a lattice? Why or Why not?

In this diagram every pair has GLB and LUB.

Comment: What are you still wondering about?

Comment: Your second sentence answers your first sentence.

Comment: @user43208 Unfortunately the diagram doesn't seem to agree with the second sentence...

Comment: @anon Ah, you are correct. Neither b nor c can be the lub of d and e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a lattice, because the pair $\{d,e\}$ has no least upper bound; it has upper bounds $a,b,c$ but no **least** upper bound.

Likewise, the pair $\{b,c\}$ has no greatest lower bound.

Comment: Isn't the relation to be interpreted as the transitive closure of the diagram?

Comment: @dfeuer Sure. But bof is correct: if for example $b$ were the lub of $d$ and $e$, then for any element $x$ such that $d \leq x$ and $e \leq x$, we would have $b \leq x$. Now apply this to $x = c$: it doesn't work. Similarly, no other upper bound of $d, e$ is a least upper bound.

Comment: @bof, ah yes, I missed that. Whoops!

Comment: Is it because of b and c are equal?

Comment: @bof: If we remove edge b-e or c-d then will it be a lattice?